# Upload file after changes locally in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am traversing to the below location to the properties file : `"global.properties"`

```
String currentPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
File appPropDir = new File(currentPath, "properties");
File app_prop_file = new File(appPropDir, "global.properties");
```

After making changes to a particular parameter in "global.properties", I want to know how to upload the file to the same location. For instance, here I am appending the "propFileName" to the end of property : product + ".app.product.types". After making this append, how to upload the file "global.properties" to the user.dir

Entire code :

```
public static synchronized void updateGlobalPropFile(String product_name, String file_name) throws Exception {
    // logger.debug("Entry-->
    // com.manh.ci.eaas.util.TemplateUtil.updateGlobalPropFile");
    System.out.println("in updateGlobalPropFile");
    String downloadLoc = "";
    String mmcType;
    String vers;
    String box, userId, password, location, key;
    int port;
    port = 22;

    String currentPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    File appPropDir = new File(currentPath, "properties");
    File app_prop_file = new File(appPropDir, "global.properties");

    downloadLoc = app_prop_file.toString();

    port = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("ssh_connection_port"));

    port = 22;

    String product = product_name;
    String file = file_name;

    String propFileName = "file";

    String changeKey = product + ".app.product.types";
    System.out.println("changeKey>>" + changeKey);
    // download global.properties instead of using local copy
    String globalPropFileLoc = downloadLoc;
    try (BufferedReader br =
         new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(globalPropFileLoc))))) {
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line = "";
        String tempLine = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.startsWith(changeKey) && line.contains(changeKey) &&
                (line.substring(0, changeKey.length()).equals(changeKey))) {

                String strChangeKey = line.substring(changeKey.length() + 1);
                // System.out.println("strChangeKey>>"+strChangeKey);
                if (strChangeKey.equalsIgnoreCase("") || strChangeKey.equalsIgnoreCase(" ")) {
                    // chek if value after = is empty for a newly added changekey : don't add comma
                    // for first value
                    tempLine = line + propFileName;
                } else {
                    tempLine = line + "," + propFileName;
                }
            } else {
                tempLine = line;
            }
            lines.add(tempLine);
        }

        if (lines.size() != 0) {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(globalPropFileLoc)));
            String finalStr = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
                finalStr = finalStr + lines.get(i) + "\n";
            }
            out.write(finalStr);
            System.out.println("updated global prop file");
            out.close();
        }

        uploadFile();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // logger.debug(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Just help me with the `uploadFile();` in the above code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is the problem about Java or Javascript now? Also there is no code for the upload comment in the snippet, please explain!

Comment: It is the uploadfile() method . I just want to know how to upload the file global.properties  in the same location

Comment: The method posted is called `updateGlobalPropFile` and calls `uploadfile()` but I cannot find the implementation of `uploadfile()`. How can somebody help you with `uploadfile()` when you are not providing it?

Comment: Uploadfile() is  just for reference . I am trying to figure out what to write in the method so that I am able to upload the file global.properties in that same location i.e user.dir here . Sorry for not being very clear about the issue . Thanks for the help .

Comment: I am trying to find out what to write in uploadfile() here .

Comment: You are talking about uploading, I see you are referencing port 22 which is SSH. Are you using an SSH library, which one?

Comment: No I am not using . As evident in the first code snippet I am using user.dir to traverse to global.properties. After changes I want to upload global.properties in the same location . That location is a local location as in user.dir

Comment: Kindly ignore ssh here

Comment: Then with upload you mean save? Look at Java 8 `Files.write()` which allows string lines to a file on the local disk.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
public void uploadFile(final List<String> lines, final String targetFilePath) throws IOException {
        Files.write(Paths.get(targetFilePath), lines);
}
```